# UTF8 using AWS S3 and Nextjs getStaticProps

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, utf-8, next.js

When i use a getStaticProps, getting posts from Wordpress CMS using this example (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-wordpress) in my wordpress, only when i upload this files to amazon s3, i get the utf8 errors, only to this data

[image]

i trying to use utf8 in api, like this

```
const { data } = await axios({
    url: API_URL,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    },
    data: payload,
  });
```

In local this errors didnt appear

Comment: I partly solved this input manually Content-Type only to text/html;charset=utf-8. But i need to do this on package.json, and i got stucked

Answer (score 1):

I partly solved this input manually Content-Type only to text/html;charset=utf-8. But i need to do this on package.json, and i got stucked

Fix using 2 commands in package.json

```
aws --profile uaubox s3 sync --delete --acl public-read out/ 's3://mysite.com.br' --exclude '*.html' && aws --profile uaubox s3 sync --delete --acl public-read out/ 's3://mysite.com.br' --exclude '*' --include '*.html' --content-type 'text/html;charset=utf-8'
```